# Spark Streaming: Why internal processing costs are so high to handle user state of a few MB?

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Based on our experiments we see that stateful Spark Streaming internal processing costs take significant amount of time when state becomes more than a million of objects. As a result latency suffers, because we have to increase batch interval to avoid unstable behavior (processing time > batch interval).

It has nothing to do with specifics of our app, since it can be reproduced by code below.

**What are exactly those Spark internal processing/infrastructure costs that take it so much time to handle user state? Is there any options to decrease processing time besides of simply increasing batch interval?**

We planned to use state extensively: at least 100MB or so on a each of a few nodes to keep all data in memory and only dump it once in hour.

Increasing batch interval helps, but we want to keep batch interval minimal.

The reason is probably not space occupied by state, but rather large object graph, because when we changed list to large array of primitives, the problem gone.

Just a guess: it might has something to do with `org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator` used internally by Spark, because it shows up while profiling from time to time.

[image]

Here is simple demo to reproduce the picture above on modern iCore7:

- less than 15 MB of state
- no stream input at all
- quickest possible (dummy) 'updateStateByKey' function
- batch interval 1 second
- checkpoint (required by Spark, must have) to local disk
- tested both locally and on YARN

Code:

```
package spark;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SlowSparkStreamingUpdateStateDemo {

    // Very simple state model
    static class State implements Serializable {
        final List<String> data;
        State(List<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                // Tried KryoSerializer, but it does not seem to help much
                //.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .setAppName(SlowSparkStreamingUpdateStateDemo.class.getName());

        JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));
        javaStreamingContext.checkpoint("checkpoint"); // a must (if you have stateful operation)

        List<Tuple2<String, State>> initialRddGeneratedData = prepareInitialRddData();
        System.out.println("Estimated size, bytes: " + SizeEstimator.estimate(initialRddGeneratedData));
        JavaPairRDD<String, State> initialRdd = javaStreamingContext.sparkContext().parallelizePairs(initialRddGeneratedData);

        JavaPairDStream<String, State> stream = javaStreamingContext
                .textFileStream(".") // fake: effectively, no input at all
                .mapToPair(input -> (Tuple2<String, State>) null) //  fake to get JavaPairDStream
                .updateStateByKey(
                        (inputs, maybeState) -> maybeState, // simplest possible dummy function
                        new HashPartitioner(javaStreamingContext.sparkContext().defaultParallelism()),
                        initialRdd); // set generated state

        stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> { // simplest possible action (required by Spark)
            System.out.println("Is empty: " + rdd.isEmpty());
            return null;
        });

        javaStreamingContext.start();
        javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
    }

    private static List<Tuple2<String, State>> prepareInitialRddData() {
        // 'stateCount' tuples with value = list of size 'dataListSize' of strings of length 'elementDataSize'
        int stateCount = 1000;
        int dataListSize = 200;
        int elementDataSize = 10;
        List<Tuple2<String, State>> initialRddInput = new ArrayList<>(stateCount);
        for (int stateIdx = 0; stateIdx < stateCount; stateIdx++) {
            List<String> stateData = new ArrayList<>(dataListSize);
            for (int dataIdx = 0; dataIdx < dataListSize; dataIdx++) {
                stateData.add(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(elementDataSize));
            }
            initialRddInput.add(new Tuple2<>("state" + stateIdx, new State(stateData)));
        }
        return initialRddInput;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try asking the question in the mailing list?

Comment: @eliasah I have [duplicated](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-Streaming-Why-internal-processing-costs-are-so-high-to-handle-user-state-of-a-few-MB-td24640.html) it there yesterday

Comment: Did you benchmark over different serializers?

Comment: @eliasah Only default and Kryo, but the picture did not change.

Comment: Found some results after profiling: [YourKit snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RAw8EnyrcEM1h5VkdvM2pJZXM). It turns out that a lot of time is spent in `org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator`. Also YourKit detects it as hot spot. Might be a performance issue.

Comment: I think you performance profiling just have similar shape as mentioned in design spec, It should be caused by improper design of updateStateByKey API and it will scan all the stateful keys every time.

Comment: Thanks for reference, their new "tracking API" should match our case, indeed. We will try it once 1.6 is released and then update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State management has been improved in spark 1.6.
please refer to SPARK-2629 Improved state management for Spark Streaming;

And in the detailed design spec:
[Improved state management in Spark Streaming](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NoALLyd83zGs1hNGMm0Pc5YOVgiPpMHugGMk6COqxxE/edit#)

**One performance drawback is metioned as below:**

Need for more optimized state management that does not scan every key
Current updateStateByKey scan every key in every batch interval, even if there is no data for  that key. While this semantics is useful is some workloads, most workloads require only ``scanning and updating the state for which there is new data. And only a small percentage of all the state needs to be touched for that in every batch interval. `The cogroup-based implementation of updateStateByKey is not designed for this; cogroup scans all the keys every time. In fact, this causes the batch processing times of updateStateByKey to increase with the number of keys in the state, even if the data rate stays fixed.`
[image]